# Dictionary returned from a function not accessible in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Looks simple enough but i think the object is going out of scope!
I have a function to construct a Dictionary -

```
     def fill_dictionary(d_list,n_pat):
     my_dict = {}
     my_text = []
     my_list = []
     f_list = []
     tmp_list = []
     for word in d_list:
            if not(re.search(r'\#',word)) and not (re.search(r'ecl_attribute_def\   ecl_job_attr_def\[\]',word)):
                  tmp_list.append(word)
                  my_text = ''.join(tmp_list)
                  l = []
                  l = my_text.split(";")
                  for x in l:
                      my_list =[item.strip() for item in x.split("|")]
                      my_dict = {my_list[0]:my_list[1:]}

       return my_dict
```

and being called from the main function -

```
attr_d = {}
for line in tmplf:
     skipped_blocks_ecl_tmpl.append(line)
     attr_d = fill_dictionary(skipped_blocks_ecl,new_pattern)
```

but now somewhere down i want to use this dictionary (attr_d) to replace values in the file.

```
for line in skipped_blocks_ecl:
    for i, j in attr_d.iteritems():
         print i, "=" ,j
         if line == attr_d[i]:
```

But attr_d doesn't seem to have any value here,can anyone please help?

Comment: In your first code block you have ```for x in l:```, where is ```l``` coming from?

Comment: Could you provide the code between the second and the third part, the problem might very well be there.

Comment: Nope i have snipped some code from the function.the function works correctly and it returns the dict as well which gets stored in attr_d coz i printed that and can see the populated dictionary

Comment: It's a huge code can't be fitted there

Comment: Your function returns a dictionary, but it does not work correctly - see my answer

Comment: Just checked - the thing is even if i try to print attr_d in the second block outside the for loop it's not displaying the value!

Comment: nope that is not correct- see here the print displayed before return -

Comment: this is how the dict gets populated a comment as a key and a structure as a value- '/* JOB_ATR_exec_host */': ['{ ATTR_depend,                   \n\t\tREAD_WRITE,\n                ATR_TYPE_LIST,\n\t\tNULL_VERIFY_DATATYPE_FUNC,\n                verify_value_dependlist']}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, on every iteration you overwrite your whole dictionary with this line

```
 my_dict = {my_list[0]:my_list[1:]}
```

I cannot say I like it, but at least your code should be changed to

```
def fill_dictionary(d_list,n_pat):
    my_dict = {}
    for x in l:
         my_list =[item.strip() for item in x.split("|")]
         my_dict[my_list[0]] = my_list[1:]

    return my_dict
```

**EDIT:**

Demonstration for OP:

```
>>> l = ['Are|you', 'absolutely|sure']
>>> print fill_dictionary(None, None)
{'Are': ['you']}
{'absolutely': ['sure']}
{'absolutely': ['sure']}
>>>
```

As you may see, your dictionary is populated - from the last string it processes. Which is most probably not what you intended.
Another point - you don't use you function arguments within function - I just supplemented them with *None*, and the function worked. You should either drop them or use them.

Comment: But where does ' l ' come from? shouldn't that be d_list?

Comment: I was not planning on fixing all the discrepancies of the code. Since OP did not complain about exception, __l__ is probably some variable in the global scope

Comment: The function fill_dictionary(d_list,n_pat): works correctly and returns a populated dictionary to attr_d

Comment: | is being used to split there are some lines which i have snipped in the function

Comment: this is how the dict gets populated a comment as a key and a structure as a value- '/* JOB_ATR_exec_host */': ['{ ATTR_depend, \n\t\tREAD_WRITE,\n ATR_TYPE_LIST,\n\t\tNULL_VERIFY_DATATYPE_FUNC,\n verify_value_dependlist']}

Comment: @user3203406, obviously you do not get from your code what you want. You presented a code that looks messy and nonsensical. So you may keep on arguing with my ghost - it's no fun trying to help someone who does not listen (especially when it is not my job). Or you may try to see a point in my answer.

Comment: The code is required to do something and its doing i put the entire func ,i dnt understand the reason for this outburst! i have also given the output!

Comment: Yes you were correct regarding the dictionary construction i tried it by testing it in another code block and it works thank you!